# Css Trick - How to align this div

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment, html

I have the following alignment:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="right-bar">
        <div class="chat-user-content"> 
          <span class="chat-user-photo">
            <img src="http://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/25963/avatars/mini/2013-avatar_(1).png" />
          </span>
            <span class="chat-user-name">Fulano Silva</span>
            <span class="chat-user-status"><img src="http://www.colorhexa.com/a7ba3d.png" /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.chat-user-status > img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
}
```

But I can not align the `<SPAN>` "user-chat-status" right without using an image. I would like the image that appears in green, were a `<DIV>` or `<SPAN>`. What am I doing wrong?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/3PduX/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/3PduX/18/

I put `display:block` to the span, which i think may have been what you missed.

---

Radu Chelariu's idea was even better though. I smashed a working example together without having to use the extra span, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/3PduX/22/

It uses the `:after` pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two divisions one after other, you can use clear:both; in current div. 
If you want to align the div to right,you can use .
I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend, but it seems we already have something that works just above! Hugs!

Answer (score 0):

Pish, posh. Images for UI are silly. That's why we have pseudo-elements!

Basically, you just have to replace your image with a `:after` or `:before` and style that accordingly.  Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/sickdesigner/N99j3/

Cheers!